# Android App - Load data from internet to Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-volley, loader

I am trying to fetch the release date data for upcoming movie from https://api.themoviedb.org/ and pass it into broadcast receiver, and later use it to show notification when today date equals the movie release date. I tried using Volley but it seem its not working. So my question is what is the best way to load data from internet and pass it into broadcast receiver?

Comment: a rough idea in my head: do all your RESTFUL request with Retrofit, persist your data with sqlite & trigger notification every day by querying sqlite

Comment: Ah.. thank you. It sounds like a good idea. i will try it